# Creating a prototype for a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, prototype

I might be doing this wrong, but it seems like a good place to use a prototype.

I have an email form. Each input of that form that will be validated has an object. The prototype for that object is...

```
var contactInput = function(placeholder, validateFuntion) {
  this.placeholder = placeholder;
  this.value = "";
  var error = true;
  this.setError = function(errorValue) {
    if(typeof(errorValue) === "boolean") {
      error = errorValue;
    } else {
      return false;
      console.log(".setError argument must be boolean.");
    }
  };
  this.getError = function() {
     return error;
  }
  var errorMessage = "";
    this.setErrorMessage = function(errorMessageValue) {
    if(typeof(errorMessageValue) === "string") {
      errorMessage = errorMessageValue;
    } else {
      return false;
      console.log(".setErrorMessage argument must be string.");
    }
  };
  this.getErrorMessage = function() {
     return errorMessage;
  }
  this.validateFunction = validateFunction;
}
```

The problem I'm having here related to the `validateFunction` property. There are three of these inputs. Each one of their validation functions is largely similar. They only differ in operations to validate the values, and the error messages they produce when false.

One of them looks like this...

```
function(inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === "") {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = "You did not provide a name.";
      return "error.png";
    } else if (inputValue.length > 50) {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = "Name must be under 50 characters.";
      return "error.png";
    } else {
      this.error = false;
      return "tick.png";
    }
      }
```

And another looks like this...

```
function(inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === "") {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = "You did not provide an email.";
      return "error.png";
    } else if ( !/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(inputValue) ) {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = "The email you provided was invalid.";
      return "error.png";
    } else {
      this.error = false;
      return "tick.png";
    }
      }
```

I would like to create a prototype for the validation functions, that I can then create three instances of validation functions with. Then I will use the prototype for the inputs (the one I already have) to create he three instances of the inputs, using the instances of the validation functions I created to set the `validateFunction` method of my input instances.

I can't think of how one would accomplish it, or if it even should be done this way. Even it shouldn't be done, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you're using the term `prototype` in the typical way.  It sounds more like what you just want is a single common/shared function that you can pass some arguments to rather than copying most of the code into several functions that are mostly the same, but slightly different.  In Javascript, that's just a shared function, not a `prototype`.

Comment: @jfriend00 That could work also. However, there are a couple reasons I would want to do it this way. If this was possible the individual functions would "persist". That would enable me to call each function without having to offer multiple arguments. In this case it brings my argument count down from from 5 to 1. Having to lug the arguments around ruins the whole point.

Comment: You can make a common function body containing 98% of the functionality and then create three shell functions that do nothing but pass the right arguments to your common function.  Then, you get the best of both worlds. A simple function to call for each of the validators and the common code in one shared functoin. FYI, this is basic programming structure (factoring out common code into a shared function).  If this is something you aren't familiar with, then you would probably benefit from some programming coursework of some kind as it would really help you to learn more of this type of thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm home taught, and have worked in the industry for a couple years now. I'm just barely starting to come out of my shell and becoming a real developer. It seemed like something that could be accomplished using classes, or something similar to classes. If you would post an answer, I would be happy to accept it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, your terminology is somewhat confusing, I would not call anything here "prototype for a function".

Prototype is an object with is used as, well, a prototype to create other objects.
In javascript it just happens that you use `function` as a constructor for objects.

Few notices regarding your implementation:

1. The code after return will not ever be executed. And the `console.log` is a bad way to inform about the error (better throw an error):

   ```
   } else {
     return false;
     console.log(".setError argument must be boolean.");
   }
   ```
2. In terms of OOP it is not good to have getters and setters, this way you expose the object state to the world. Better way is to treat the object as a micro-computer, a black box which you can ask to do some work.
   All the initialization data is passed into the constructor, so you don't need setters and the work related to the data inside object is done by the objects, so you should not need getters as well.
3. There are two ways to implement the slightly different behavior - inheritance, where child classes implement the difference or composition, where the difference is moved to another object(s).
   What to use depends on the situation.

One of the possible ways to implement your inputs is this, using the inheritance:

```
function ContactInput(selector, placeholder) {
  // properties are prefixed with underscore to notify the programmer that they are
  // 'private' (should not be accessed outside of this class or subclasses)
  this._element = document.querySelector(selector);
  this._placeholder = placeholder;
}

ContactInput.prototype.validate() {
    // this should be implemented in child classes
    throw 'Not implemented';
}

// Private method (prefixed with underscore), also to be used only by this object
ContactInput.prototype._renderSuccess(message, image) {
    message = message || "";
    image = image || "tick.png";
    // show the success div near the element (actually it is better to use css, 
    // so it will be not necessary to pass the `tick.png` and `error.png`
    // around, you could just change the element's css class here to show the tick)
}

// Private
ContactInput.prototype._renderError(message, image) {
    message = message || "Validation error";
    image = image || "error.png";
    // show the error div near the element
}

// Private
ContactInput.prototype._getValue() {
    return this._element.value;
}

function NameInput(placeholder) {
    ContactInput.call(this, placeholder);
}
NameInput.prototype = Object.create(ContactInput.prototype);

NameInput.prototype.validate() {
    var value = this._getValue();
    if (!value) {
        return this.renderError("You did not provide a name.", 'error.png');
    }
    if (value.length > 50) {
        return this.renderError("Name must be under 50 characters.", 'error.png');
    }
    return this.renderSuccess();
}

function EmailInput(placeholder) {
    ContactInput.call(this, placeholder);
}
EmailInput.prototype = Object.create(ContactInput.prototype);

EmailInput.prototype.validate() {
    var value = this._getValue();
    if (!value) {
        return this.renderError("You did not provide an email.", 'error.png');
    }
    if ( !/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(value) ) {
        return this.renderError("The email you provided was invalid.", 'error.png');
    }
    return this.renderSuccess();
}
```

I am not sure about how you use the `placeholder`, so I just left it in the base class.
Depending on usage, it can be a property of the `NameInput` only (or of the `EmailInput`).

Now you can do this:

```
var inputs = [
    new NameInput('x'),
    new EmailInput('y')
];
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.validate();
});
```

Note that you don't have to do things like `input->setError('xxx')` and then `input->getError('xxx')` in some other place.
You just create the object, give it some data and let it do work based on this data.